# Viewing several classes reference info using document organizer

Tags: xcode4

Is there a way to get multiple organizer windows open so I can view reference info about several classes at the same time? It's very tedious to keep doing searches and re-opening the same window. For example I want to have one window showing the NSString class ref, another showing NSCoding, another showing NSCopying, etc., so I can view them at the same time and switch quickly between them (without losing my place on each one's page). OR is there some other equivalent way of browsing multiple classes / info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging around I have not found any way to do what I was hoping with Organizer. The best suggestions all range around using alternatives such as open web browser on docs, etc. The latter is probably a good solution for most but less convenient for our group because by policy our devel systems are not allowed onto a general network. (So we are copying info to systems on the devel local network.)